# Disable get request on logout razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page (asp.net core 2.1) for logout (/identity/account/logout) which shows its view on get request and perform logout on post request. I want to remove the view and leave only the logic for logout which is the post request. I deleted OnGetAsync() method from the PageModel, but the view is still showed up if someone manually enter the url. What I want is when someone try to access this page via get request -> 404 Not Found. Like this page really doesn't exist!

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: The code isn't needed for those question. It's just a simple class with one method OnPostAsync() which has 2 lines of code: first one for logout and second for redirecting the user to home page!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can just return a 404 yourself, using `NotFound`.

Replace the existing `OnGetAsync` method with the following:

```cs
public IActionResult OnGet() =>
    NotFound();
```